# foreign key error when migrate table in laravel 5.0

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, laravel-migrations

When i try to make foreign key in my migrate file then I get error when I run migrate command . In order table I make userID as forign key so I get this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1voZh.png

Comment: could you post `orders` and `users` migration files? including it's filename.

Comment: @Tezla yes i post my migration file  at this https://gist.github.com/24singhekta/998aab6fd372a3aa35f5

Comment: when u make a foreign key u should assign the the table u r referring to like that : $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('product_id')->refrences('id')->on('products'); –

Answer (score 2):

You need to use exact same type for foreign key. In `users` you have:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

so it's unsigned int, so in `order` instead of:

```
$table->integer('userID');
```

(signed int) you need to use:

```
$table->integer('userID')->unsigned();
```

(unsigned int) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately You can follow below steps to fix your problem.

In Your User model write this code to relate orders.

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

And your "orders" tables migrations would be like this.

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('extra_detail');
    $table->integer('user_id');
});
```

In Your order model write this code to relate users.

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And your "users" tables migrations would be like this.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
});
```

Comment: This won't solve her issue with references. I suppose.

Comment: when u make a foreign key u should assign the the table u r referring to like that :  $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->refrences('id')->on('products');